# ASP.NET MVC Html.Encode - New lines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, newline, html-encode

`Html.Encode` seems to simply call `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to replace a few html specific characters with their escape sequences.

However this doesn't provide any consideration for how new lines and multiple spaces will be interpretted (markup whitespace). So I provide a text area for the a user to enter a plain text block of information, and then later display that data on another screen (using `Html.Encode`), the new lines and spacing will not be preserved.

I think there are 2 options, but maybe there is a better 3rd someone can suggest.

One option would be to just write a static method that uses HtmlEncode, and then replaces new lines in the resulting string with `<br>` and groups of multiple spaces with `&nbsp;`

Another option would be to mess about with the `white-space: pre` attribute in my style sheets - however I'm not sure if this would produce side effects when Html helper methods include new lines and tabbing to make the page source pretty.

Is there a third option, like a global flag, event or method override I can use to change how html encoding is done without having to redo the html helper methods?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`HtmlEncode` is only meant to encode characters for display in HTML.  It specifically does not encode whitespace characters.

I would go with your first option, and make it an extension method for HtmlHelper.  Something like:

```
public static string HtmlEncode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                string text, 
                                bool preserveWhitespace)
{
    // ...
}
```

You could use `String.Replace()` to encode the newlines and spaces (or `Regex.Replace` if you need better matching).

Answer (score 8):

Using the `style="white-space:pre-wrap;"` worked for me.  Per [this article](http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2009/07/24/dev-tip-preserve-whitespace-in-html-without-using/).

Answer (score 6):

If you use Razor you can do:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(strToEncode).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

in your view, or in your controller:

```
HttpServerUtility httpUtil = new HttpServerUtility();
MvcHtmlString encoded = httpUtil.HtmlEncode(strToEncode).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

I have not tested the controller method, but it should work the same way.

Comment: The controller portion will not compile.

Comment: Doesn't compile. should be: MvcHtmlString encoded = MvcHtmlString(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(Body).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));

Comment: "The type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' has no constructors defined" use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: use this instead: 
var httpUtil = new HttpServerUtilityWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Server);

Answer (score 3):

Put your output inside `<pre></pre>` and/or `<code></code>` blocks. E.g:

```
<pre>@someValue</pre> / <code>@someValue</code>
```

---

Use the equivalent css on an existing `div`:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap;">@someValue</div>
```

---

Depends whether you want the semantic markup or whether you want to fiddle with css. I think these are both neater than inserting `<br/>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns html string with new lines as br tags
    /// </summary>
    public static MvcHtmlString ConvertNewLinesToBr<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string text)
    {
        return  new MvcHtmlString(html.Encode(text).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
    }
```