# Inserting a non-breaking space in a @Html.DisplayFor when data is null or empty? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a need to insert a `&nbsp;` via `@HTML.DisplayFor` when the backing model's value is null or empty.

I've tried using data annotations

```
 [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText =" " ]
    public string  MiddleName { get; set; }
```

which does work to stick a " " where I expect it but I need to put a non-breaking space there instead.

Comment: Have you tried `NullDisplayText="&nbsp;"`?

Comment: yes, that will HTMLEncode it and display &nbsp; instead of a " ". I can turn off the HTMLEncode but that seems a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NullDisplayText = @"&nbsp;", HtmlEncode = false
```

Comment: A word of caution on this approach. If the model's value is not null and contains a character that should be encoded, such as a less than sign, then the output may not render correctly. In addition, this approach is vulnerable to HTML script injection if the model's value is from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var space = "&nbsp;";

 [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText ="@space" ]
public string  MiddleName { get; set; }
```

The issue with placing `"&nbsp;"` in that location is that it will be read as c# code.  Instead, you want it to be read as HTML code at run time, and the above should achieve this.

Comment: Tried a number of variations of your code above with no luck. I assume that you are trying to get the @space text to be placed in the HTML stream and then interpreted as Razor code?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524528/asp-net-mvc-html-encode-new-lines)

Comment: Have you tried '[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = Environment.NewLine ]
public string  MiddleName { get; set; }' ?

Comment: James, that throws an exception "attribute argument must be a constant expression of an attribute parameter type."

Comment: Forgot it is not a constant and only used at runtime.  With that said, try using 'var space = Environment.NewLine;' '...NullDisplayText = "@space"' If that doesn't work, is it populating an error?

Comment: This just displays @space when there is no value.

Comment: Ok, let me make test scenario and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Ok, so after a bit of research and a looking into a few things, give this a try `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText ="<%=&nbsp%>" ]
public string  MiddleName { get; set; }`.  Let me know.

Comment: Sorry that just gives me a  <%=&nbsp%> displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by writing a helper instead of using `@Html.DisplayFor`. This is it.

```
@helper NonBreakingSpacesIfNullOrEmpty(string field, int spaces)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
    {
        @(new HtmlString(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", spaces))))
    }
    else
    {
        @field
    }
}
```

Your code would call it like this.

```
@FooHelper.NonBreakingSpacesIfNullOrEmpty(Model.MiddleName, 1)
```

Delete the `spaces` parameter and the associated logic if you don't need the repeat functionality.