# display example cshtml code in cshtml using prettyPrint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to display some code examples on a web page using [prettyPrint](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), all are working (most is C#) aside from `cshtml`.

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

I'm not sure what should I should be doing, apparently the `<div>` shouldn't be nested within `<pre>`, and the C# functions in the cshtml are causing browser issues - changing the class to `lang-cs` or `lang-cshtml` didn't work either.

Could someone shed some light on why the code is being rendered by the browser and not being displayed by the javascript?

**Code:**
Basically I want to display code as per below.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
<div id="catalogueList">
    // some cshtml code
</div>
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "Movie" type instead of "var" in your foreach?

Comment: The code shown works, but I can't display it on a web page, as a code example.

Comment: MVC is converting those `@using` and `@html` etc.. before the server sends the page to the client. I belive HTML 5 has a `<code>` tag, never tried it with a mvc page, try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: Maybe provide some 'sample' code that doesn't do anything as it looks like your code sample is where the issue is.  ie you've not actually provided the code that has the problem, which most people would expect to see

Comment: Without seeing the code that's generating the output, it's hard to give a helpful response, but, where you have something *like* `<pre>@model.Code</pre>` change it to `<pre>@Html.Raw(model.Code)</pre>`

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't sure how to show this properly, I shall try your idea, thank you

Comment: Hmm - I suspect my suggestion is the *opposite* of what you want :)    Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524528/asp-net-mvc-html-encode-new-lines

Comment: Ah! I see your question ... you can replace the single @ to @@ and the razor engine will skip them as plain text ... just an idea

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions, unfortunately neither worked, would the entire web page help? Essentially I just want to display cshtml code on a web page with prettyPrint.js. It seems that the view engine is still trying to render the `@using` and `@foreach` etc

Comment: Yes @Sam.C! Thank you, put as answer and I'll accept, now to stop it ignoring the `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the single @ with @@ and the razor engine will skip executable code and render them as a plain text.

Update : This solution would help in directly rendering code snippets written on the view (inline with the actual razor code rendering the page). If the code snippet is dynamic and is contained in a variable then this is not required.

Update 2: Nesting a `<xmp>` opening and closing tag between the `<pre class="prettyPrint">` tags will allow for the html to all be rendered once the `@` symbols have been added to stop the razor engine rendering the example code.

**Example: **

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
    <xmp>
<div id="catalogueList">
    @@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userName)
<br />
<div id="editorRowsMovies">
            @@foreach (var item in Model.movies)
            {
                @@Html.Partial("MovieView", item)
            }
        </div>
        @@Html.ActionLink("Add", "MovieManager", null, new { id = "addItemMovies" });
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
</xmp>
</pre>
```

Comment: So, to confirm, the code being rendered is actually code entered directly on the page?  Not stored in a variable?   Might like to make that clearer in the question as you only show the desired *output* not the *input* (probably because they are the same?)

Comment: Yes you are correct .. this is assuming that the snippet is directly entered on the page. I have added some more clarification to the answer Thanks!